# Android conver audio to 16-bit PCM

Tags: android, audio, pcm, 16-bit

I have an Android project need to read any Audio format and convert it to 16-bit PCM format. Is it a possible?

If not , is possible just convert some popular audio format ?

If it possible , can somebody suggest 3rd library to do it?

Very thankful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't need a third-party library, the MediaCodec and related classes have been in the SDK since API v16: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodec.html

Comment: Thanks for your comment.
Is MediaCodec support all of audio to convert 16-bit pcm?